# Rsolr::Ext return undefined method `to_i' for ["10", "10"]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, rsolr

- I had a problem about RSolr::Ext.
- When i try to query with params `page` and `per_page` use library `rsolr-ext` in order to connect to Apache Solr.

And i get an error same as:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for ["10", "10"]:Array
from /home/khanhpn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@music/gems/rsolr-ext-1.0.3/lib/rsolr-ext/response.rb:27:in `rows'
```

This is my code:

```
@solr_connection = RSolr::Ext.connect(
  url: "http://localhost:8080/solr/music",
  open_timeout: 10,
  read_timeout: 10,
  retry_503: 2)

solr_params = {
     :page => 0,
     :per_page => 10,
     :field_names => [:id, :title],
     :queries => "xuan"
}

solr_connection.find(solr_params)
```

Hope that everybody can support me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with `:field_names` key, which seems to be unsupported by [`RSolr::Ext#find`](https://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr-ext#find) method. Did you mistaken with `:queries`, `:phrases` or other available ?